# xbindkeys_show: exec: wish not found

Tags: xbindkeys

I installed `xbindkeys` via `sudo apt-get install xbindkeys`

Now when I run `xbindkeys_show` I get:

```
$ xbindkeys_show 
/usr/bin/xbindkeys_show: 3: exec: wish: not found
```

The question is: *How can I run this program? What dependencies are missing?*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In 13.10 I do not have a `wish` package.

```
 (0)asus-romano:~% apt-file search /usr/bin/wish
 tk: /usr/bin/wish-default
 tk8.4: /usr/bin/wish8.4
 tk8.5: /usr/bin/wish8.5
 tk8.6: /usr/bin/wish8.6
```

So I suppose the package is `tk` (and probably `tcl`)

```
 apt-get install tcl tk
```

(but this is a bug in packaging... if it's needed  should be a dependency)

Comment: Then I should probably file a bug report

Comment: present in focal too.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the package `wish`.

The package `xbindkeys` only suggests `wish` so it is not installed as a dependency by default.

Use something like

```
sudo apt-get install --install-suggests xbindkeys
```

to install a package with the packages it suggests

Comment: Exactly like Rmano said there is no wish in Ubuntu 13.10. I looked for that :P. Maybe I should have mentioned that.